# Envers audit table does not rollback in spring-boot integration tests annotated with @Transactional

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, hibernate-envers, spring-boot-test, spring-data-envers

I am trying to figure out why @Transactional does not rollback data in envers audit table after each test and how to fix it. 
How can I make that happen in spring integration tests?

I have tried with @DirtiesContext and that makes it work but it's rather workaround and makes tests run much longer which I don't like.

Does any of you have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: share the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate Envers acts as a transaction-commit-time audit solution.  What that ultimately means is that all the persistence changes that happen during a transaction are examined and a set of work unit operations are cached in memory.  In short, the only time Envers flushes operations to the audit schema is immediately before the commit of a successful transaction.

So how does this all work from a Hibernate point of view?

Hibernate Envers registers 2 very critical callback operations with Hibernate ORM when a transaction that operates on an audited entity is detected, a *before* and *after* transaction completion callback.  The *before* callback is what actually performs the flushing of the audit changes to the audit tables and the *after* is responsible for cleaning up any resource allocations that are related to the transaction.

The only time that the *before* callback actually happens is when the hibernate transaction coordinator is asked to commit the transaction.  If the transaction has been marked for rollback when the commit is requested, then the *before* callback is skipped.

The *after* callback always happens no matter the transaction status.

It would seem whats likely happening is `@Transactional` is creating the transaction boundary and the method is then invoked to perform its operations and when the method exits, the annotation forces a transaction commit leading to the observed behavior.

I can see a few options for you:

1. Override transaction behavior for tests to be *read-only*.
2. Design tests to clean-up their test data after validating the test use case.
3. Design tests to work even if existing test data exists in the tables.
4. Disable Envers via configuration if it isn't needed as a part of that integration test.

Comment: Thank for the answer. It helped me organize my idea around envers and how it happens to update it's tables under the hood. 
I decided to got with "clean-up after test" solution, seems the most logic and clean for me.

Comment: @zmaselke could you please tell how did you clean up db after the test?